# In Docusign iOS sdk DSMManager.login(withEmail: ..) having some trouble

Tags: ios, swift, docusignapi

Docusign iOS sdk DSMManager.login(withEmail: ..)  method have parameter withEmail, password, integrationkey, host. In integration key I'm passing my app's integration key and for host "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/"

for email and password i did try my developer account credentials but it gaves

some : Error Domain=user.additional.data.fetch.error Code=-1011 "Unable to fetch additional data for user - The URL provided does not resolve to a resource. Consumer Disclosure does not exist." UserInfo={DSM_com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600001c94120> { URL: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/********/consumer_disclosure } { Status Code: 404, Headers {

Code:
DSMManager.login(withEmail: "email*@gmail.com",
password: "123456",
integratorKey: integratorKey,
host: hostUrl) { (accountInfo, error) in
if (error != nil)
{
NSLog("Error logging in")
// display error prompt
}
else
{
NSLog("User authenticated")
// segue to main navigation controller
}
}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Pinkesh! It's great you described your problem and the error given, but it would also be helpful to post the actual code from your project to get a better idea of the approach you're taking.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Legacy Authentication (using cleartext password) is no longer allowed for new applications being built with DocuSign.

Please see more details in the [OAuth 2.0 migration page](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/oauth2-requirements-migration/).

[Blog post announcing the change.](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/october-2022-oauth2-required).